# Show bars one by one Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm looking to display bar chart values one by one, i.e. if there are 3 bars 1st bar should unfurl completely then 2nd bar then 3rd bar. I couldn't find anything relevant in Chart.js documentation would it be possible to achieve such effect with chart.js

Sample code below that I'm using to generate chart currently

```
       function loadChart(chartConfig) {

        var ctx = document.getElementById(chartConfig.id).getContext('2d');

        var horizontalBarChartData = {
            labels: chartConfig.labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: chartConfig.barHoverlabel,
                backgroundColor: chartConfig.barColor,
                borderColor: (chartConfig.borderColor ? chartConfig.borderColor : 
                               chartConfig.barColor),
                borderWidth: 3,
                barThickness: chartConfig.barThickness,
                data: chartConfig.data,
            }]

        };

        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: horizontalBarChartData,
            options: {
                animation: {
                    duration: chartConfig.animationDuration,
                    easing: (chartConfig.animationType ? chartConfig.animationType : 
                             'easeOutQuart')
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            gridLines: {
                                zeroLineWidth: 2,
                                zeroLineColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                                borderDash: [4],
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                fontSize: chartConfig.xLabelFontSize,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            gridLines: {
                                zeroLineWidth: 0,
                                borderDash: [4]
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                fontSize: chartConfig.yLabelFontSize
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }
        });

    };

        var chartConfig = {
        id: 'canvas',
        animationDuration: 3000,
        xLabelFontSize: 18,
        yLabelFontSize: 22,
        barColor: '#00c17e',
        barThickness: 16,
        barHoverlabel: 'Distribution',
        labels: ['Less than 20', '21-50', '51-100'],
        data: [45, 27, 96]
    };

window.onload = loadChart(chartConfig);
```

Comment: we can draw one row of data at a time, then using the [animation `onComplete` event](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/animations.html#animation-configuration), we can add and draw the next row of data. however, when drawing the second row of data, the first bar will re-animate along with the second, and so on. will that work?

Comment: @WhiteHat I ended up using slightly modified version of your solution to avoid reanimation. i.e On first load I kept data as [0, 0, 96] and onComplete event updated the array to [0, 27, 96] and so on for each run. So that it eliminated previous bar re-animation.

Comment: very clever, glad you were able to resolve...